# ob_start() hides the output to the screen

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem with the function ob_start(). I'm developing a website where I'm presenting a php file that contains a report that I let the user send it to himself by mail.
The problem is, when I use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() in order to define what I want to be sent, all the code that is between these 2 functions is not visible to the user on the website.

```
<?php
$report='';
//the code here is visible in the website
ob_start(); //the code from here is going to the email and is not visible
.
.
.
$report.=ob_get_clean(); //after this all the rest of the code is visible
```

What can I do in order to show the code that goes to the mail on the website?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: That's exactly what output buffering does. It does capture the output, and won't display it after you _clean() it up. If you want the content to go to said mail *and* the page output, then manually print() the collected output out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't clean the buffer:

```
$report .= ob_get_contents();
```

You could also `ob_flush();` or `ob_end_flush();` after that line, but it shouldn't matter as all output will be displayed when the script ends.  Depends on whether you want to continue output buffering or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ob_get_flush()`. It cleans the buffer and prints the output. Alternatively `echo $report;` immediately after `ob_get_clean()`.